# How to know the name of the windows device in C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a code which shares information between the windows and android devices. I need to share the name of the devices also.
I used String model = Build.MODEL; for getting the name of the android device in android code. But I am not sure what should I use to know the name of windows device in C# code.
I tried googleing but did not help. Can someone help me in this..

Comment: The name of the computer? Like - *System.Environment.MachineName* ?

Comment: Use the System.Management class in combination with WMI for finding out which hardware is in the device, you can't always get the device name, since some computers could be build with custom a custom set of hardware, not build by specific manufacturers.

Comment: This question, currently, makes no sense. What are you referring to with C#? Xamarin? What you tried already? What is the error you are getting? See where I'm going with this?

Comment: Let me try the above suggestions. I was looking for the computer name. Like my computer name is "Sharath-PC".. Something like that.. Let me try these though

Comment: So what happened when you Googled for "computer name c#".  Did Google go down again?  Sheesh.

Comment: @Simon http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/google.com :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As *Nicholas V.* stated, you can use:

```
string pcName = System.Environment.MachineName;
```

to return a **string** containing the NetBIOS name of the local machine.